# How to solve state updates issue with MUI5 Select multiple

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [MUI5 Select with Checkmarks](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#checkmarks), and if the user has checked more than one checkbox, the selections should be saved in the `React useState`. The issue I have is that when I pick numerous checkboxes, just the most recent selection is saved in my `React useState.` Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried:

```
import {memo, useMemo, useState} from 'react';
import {Box, InputLabel, MenuItem, FormControl, ListItemText, Select, SelectChangeEvent, Checkbox} from '@mui/material';

const Filters = memo(({filters}: {filters: FiltersResponse}) => {
  const [filterName, setFilterName] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState<FiltersResponse>({Name: [], Environment: []});

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof filterName>, key: keyof FiltersResponse) => {
    const {
      target: {value}
    } = event;
    // here previous user selections should be shown, but not working.
    const selections = selectedFilter[key].concat(value);
    setSelectedFilter({...selectedFilter, [key]: selections});
  };

  const filtersList = useMemo(() => {
    return Object.entries(filters).map(([key, value]: [key: string, value: string[]]) => {
      return (
        <Box sx={{display: 'flex'}} key={key}>
          <FormControl sx={{m: 1, width: '100%'}}>
            <InputLabel id={`${key}-checkbox-label`}>{key}</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId={`${key}-checkbox-label`}
              id={`${key}-filter-checkbox`}
              multiple
              value={filterName} // ignore this is from mui example
              onChange={(evt) => handleChange(evt, key as keyof FiltersResponse)}
              renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')} // ignore this is from mui example
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {value.map((name) => (
                <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                  <Checkbox checked={filterName.indexOf(name) > -1} /> // ignore this is from mui example
                  <ListItemText primary={name} />
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Box>
      );
    });
  }, [filters]);

  console.log(selectedFilter);

  return <>{filtersList}</>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you community, Figured out, separating the FilterList as a new component fixed the issue.